# Android Studio / ¿Como hacer clickeables distintas partes de un texto?

Tags: android, android-studio, text, click

**(PROBLEMA SOLUCIONADO)**

Estoy intentando capturar **textos variables** pero que poseen en común una división entre la parte **izquierda y derecha** por medio de un símbolo mayor (**>**). Les dejo un **ejemplo** para que se vaya comprendiendo:

**($500 > $1000)**

Yo reconozco esto como que el usuario de mi aplicación **busca precios** entre $50 y $100. Digo que es un texto variable porque el usuario **puede elegir números con más o menos digitos**. **Ejemplo:**

**($5 > $10)**

El tema es que quiero que al seleccionarse el precio izquierdo se devuelva una acción como por ejemplo un mensaje que diga "Precios desde $5" y con el precio derecho "Precios hasta $10".

Estoy usando el método **ClickableSpan** que permite indicar desde que posición hasta que posición quieres que tu texto sea clickeable. El problema está en que no puedo pasar los números de "**posición desde**" y "**posición hasta**" como argumentos porque el largo de la cadena **varía** según la cantidad de dígitos que el usuario ingrese. **Ejemplo:**

**En la primer cadena, desde la posición 0 hasta la posición 4 hay texto, pero en la segunda cadena hay texto desde la posición 0 hasta la posición 2.**

Me gustaría que alguien me pueda indicar como proceder para lograr que, independientemente del **largo de la cadena**, la parte izquierda (anterior al signo mayor (>)) sea clickeable al igual que la parte derecha (posterior al signo mayor(>)).

**Adjunto el código con el que estoy probando**

```
//PARTES CLICKEABLES DE UN TEXTO
            //SPLIT para separar la cadena en dos partes
//info_filtro es el string al que le llegan los valores del usuario.
            String divisor_info_filtro[] = info_filtro.split(">");
            String precio_desde = divisor_info_filtro[0].trim();
            String precio_hasta = divisor_info_filtro[1].trim();
            SpannableString ss;

            ClickableSpan clickable_desde = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Precio desde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };

            ClickableSpan clickable_hasta = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Precio hasta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
```

**Adjunto el código que indica desde que posición hasta que posición, el texto será clickeable**

```
ss = new SpannableString(info_filtro);
                ss.setSpan(clickable_desde,0,3, 
Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

txt_info_filtro.setText(ss);                
txt_info_filtro.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

En el código anterior se puede ver que pase las posiciones 0 y 3 como argumentos. Pero como dije, las posiciones pueden variar dependiendo cuantos dígitos haya introducido el usuario.

***//PROBLEMA A SOLUCIONAR (CAMBIO DE BACKGROUND)***
**Adjunto foto de como se ve el código funcionando (estática y no dinámicamente) el cual también me gustaría corregir para que el color del fondo del texto al ser seleccionado cambie por un color y automáticamente vuelva a no tener fondo (efecto de selección)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Espero haberme explicado bien y realmente desearía poder resolver este problema. Muchisimas gracias por leer!**

Comment: y si pones dos textview y asi controlaas a cual se le da clic

Comment: Eso me complicaría las cosas. Prefiero no hacerlo. Gracias igual por la idea!

Comment: realmente creo que usar dos TextViews independientes sería la solución más sencilla pues te evitas hacer los splits y demás rollos, al final para que quieres presición milimétrica en el onClick si al final el usuario nunca se preocupará por tocar con el dedo los dígitos del precio exacto, solo le picará sobre el texto del precio y ya

Comment: Hola, @TomasM ¿El botón o indicador que ilustraste que se llama "Editar" es el que ejecuta la acción para cambiar los nuevos valores en los Text, cierto?

Comment: Exacto Fernando. Pero ese botón no está programado. No influye en nada en este problema.

Comment: Ya solucioné el problema por mi cuenta. Solamente me faltaría saber como cambiar el color del texto clickeable. Les dejo lo que hice por si a alguien le interesa: int pos_a = 0; for(int j = 0; j<info_filtro.length(); j++){
                        String detector = info_filtro.substring(j,j+1);
                        if(detector.equalsIgnoreCase(">")){
                            pos_a = j+1;
                        }
                    }
                    ss.setSpan(clickable_hasta,pos_a,info_filtro.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Comment: @TomasM creo que la mejor opcion es usar dos textView en este caso particular, hacer clickeable una parte del texto y no el resto solo tiene sentido en textos largos donde la parte clickeable es dinamica, este no es el caso y terminaras con un area de click muy pequeña, vos no lo notaras, pero el usuario final si

Comment: Ya lo solucioné. Gracias igual. Sabes como cambiar el color al ser el texto seleccionado??

Comment: Tomas, aunque la pregunta puede estar relacionada te **recomiendo** crear una pregunta nueva y dejando la antigua tal y como estaba

Comment: Tenes razón. No quería hacerlo porque pensé que sería molesto para la comunidad pero veo que será lo mejor. Muchas gracias por comentar!

Comment: Por favor no coloques solucionado al título de tu pregunta, en su lugar por favor considera leer [answer]

Comment: https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2016/08/android-clickablespan-example.html

Comment: @FrEqDe Esta pregunta ya está cerrada. Me ayudaría mucho que puedas decirme algo acerca de esta nueva que hice https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320456/android-studio-como-cambiar-el-color-de-selecci%c3%b3n-de-un-texto-clickeable-con Gracias por comentar!!