# Android Studio / ¿Como cambiar el color de selección de un texto clickeable con ClickableSpan?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, click

**ClickableSpan** permite hacer clickeables distintas partes de un mismo texto, las cuales **al ser clickeadas** cambian su background al color que le especifiquemos con el siguiente código:

```
txt.setHighlightColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

El problema es que el color de fondo (background) de la parte clickeable del texto **no vuelve a su color original**. Me explico: Se selecciona la palabra "**Click**" del texto "Haz **Click** aquí" y la palabra "Click" adquiere el fondo "LTGRAY" **permanentemente**.

Me gustaría lograr un **efecto de selección** en donde al tocar "Click" se coloree el fondo con "LTGRAY" pero que **al soltar** el click, esta palabra vuelva a **no tener fondo** (o tener uno determinado).

**Adjunto el código que hace clickeable mi texto**

```
TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
SpannableString ss = null;
ClickableSpan metodo_clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Hiciste click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

ss.setSpan(metodo_clickable, 1, 9,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
txt.setText(ss);              
txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
txt.setHighlightColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

**Adjunto foto de como se ve el fondo del texto clickeado el cual permanece así hasta que se cierre la aplicación**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Agradezco mucho su lectura**

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres, porque desde el punto de vista del usuario, pulsa con el dedo y tapa lo que pulsa, con lo que a menos que el texto seleccionable sea más grande que el dedo, no verá nada, pero bueno. Prueba con `onTouch` en vez de `onClick`. En el `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` haces lo que haces ahora, y en `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, haces lo contrario, osea, dejarlo con el color original.

Comment: @SuperG280 Si que entendiste lo que quiero, por lo que agradezco un montón tu respuesta. El texto será más grande que el dedo por lo que no habría problema. Me dices que cambie el onTouch por onClick pero: ¿Probaste eso? El ClickableSpan solo permite la implementación de onClick!

Comment: Cierto, no deriva de View... Pues lo tienes complicado. Mira a ver si [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856105/change-the-text-color-of-a-single-clickablespan-when-pressed-without-affecting-o) te da alguna solución, pero es bastante más complejo de lo que pensabas...

Comment: Estoy leyendo el link que me enviaste y si que es complejo. Aún así, es el mismo problema que yo tengo por lo que creo que me será de utilidad. Voy a revisarlo en profundidad. Muchas gracias por compartir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy fácil hacer lo que quieres.

En Android, hay muchos tipos de Spans para darle estilo a los textos.

Pero vamos a enfocarnos en uno principal que resolverían tu problema:

> [BackgroundColorSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan): Cambia el color de fondo del texto al que se adjunta el span.

Una solución, es implementar `View.OnTouchListener` desde la clase control que creas para manejar tu `ClickableSpan` y jugar con los eventos `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` el cual se activa al mantener presionada la vista y `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` que se dispara al levantarla. Dichos eventos se disparan solo una vez por cada accion correspondiente.

En dichos eventos, debes setear el `Span` para que pueda crear el efecto que quieras.

> **OJO:** cada vez que asignas un `Span` a un `Spannable`, estos permanecen. Si quieres deshacer un `Span`, debes eliminarlo
>   manualmente según la clase que implementaste para el Span. Por
>   ejemplo, tu `Spannable` puede tener muchos Spans diferentes a la vez;
>   `ForegroundColorSpan`, `BackgroundColorSpan`, `ClickableSpan`, esto
>   hace que no puedas implementar dos Spans de un mismo tipo a la vez,
>   porque solo tomara como prioridad el primero que afecte una propiedad,
>   es por ello que cada vez que quieras setear un mismo span dentro de un
>   rango en el `Spannable` debes eliminarlo manualmente.

Tanto `onClick` como `onTouch`, son dos eventos que intercaran con tus acciones en la pantalla, pero `onTouch` es mas general porque es el padre que detona esos eventos. Estos no se implementan a la vez y es por eso que debes hacer unos ajustes en `onTouch` para poder disparar tu evento Click. Se retorna true para indicarle que dicho evento es quien tomo la acción y cuando haces el `ACTION_UP` disparas el evento click. Ten en cuenta que no estas tomando las demás acciones como `ACTION_MOVE`, es por ello que donde sea que levantes el dedo luego de hacerle el evento `ACTION_DOWN` a la vista, se disparara Click.

Te dejo un código rápido de ejemplo para lograr lo que quieres:

**Clickable.java**

```
public class Clickable extends ClickableSpan implements View.OnTouchListener{
        private TextView mTarget;
        private int mDefaultColor;
        private int mPressedColor;

        public void wrap(@NonNull TextView view){
            this.mTarget = view;
        }


        public void enableHighlightMode(@ColorInt int defaultColor, @ColorInt int pressedColor){
            this.mDefaultColor = defaultColor;
            this.mPressedColor = pressedColor;
            this.mTarget.setOnTouchListener(this);
            setDefaultTextColor();
        }

        private void setDefaultTextColor(){

            if(mTarget.getText() instanceof  Spannable) {
                Spannable editable = (Spannable) mTarget.getText();
                editable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(mDefaultColor), 0, editable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }

        private void setPressedTextColor(){
            if(mTarget.getText() instanceof  Spannable) {

                Spannable editable = (Spannable) mTarget.getText();
                BackgroundColorSpan[] spans = null;

                spans = editable.getSpans(0, editable.length(), BackgroundColorSpan.class);

                for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
                    editable.removeSpan(spans[i]);

                editable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(mPressedColor), 0, editable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) { /* No default implementation */ }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    setPressedTextColor();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    setDefaultTextColor();
                    onClick(mTarget);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Y para configurar tu ClickableSpan:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Hello World");
textView.setText(spannableString);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Clickable clickable = new Clickable() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hiciste click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
clickable.wrap(textView);
clickable.enableHighlightMode(Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLUE);
spannableString.setSpan(clickable, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Puedes modificar el código, hacer validaciones como quieras y jugar con los Spans. Happy coding. Saludos.

**Edit**: si quieres aplicar un `Span` a un texto en específico, debes indicarle las posiciones en el método `setSpan`.

Una forma es, crear un método en tu control dónde le pases un `String` para pintarlo.

Ejemplo:

```
private int spanStart = -1;
private int spanEnd = -1;


public void applySpanOn(String text){
           if(mTarget == null || text == null) return;

           String spanned = mTarget.getText();
           spanStart = spanned.indexOf(text);

           // Return if not found
           if(spanStart == -1) return;

           spanEnd = spanStart + text.length();
}
```

Y en los métodos `setPressedTextColor()` y `setDefaultTextColor()`:

Al código de `editable.setSpan` debes indicarle `spanStart` en vez de `0` y `spanEnd` en vez de `editable.length()`. Debes tener en cuenta que debes hacer las validaciones correspondientes con tu lógica.

Siguiendo el ejemplo, para aplicar el cambio debes hacer.

`clickable.applySpanOn("world");`

**Nota:** te invito a que busques y estudies la documentación de casa cosa que implementas en la internet. Normalmente es una guía de soluciones, no soluciones definitivas. Así podrás implementar códigos entendibles y salir a camino solo cuando no entiendes algo. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación tan detallada. Eso es algo que se valora un montón. Tu código funciona y me hiciste aprender que existe una clase la cual administra algunas de estas acciones. Copié tu código tal cual y logró funcionar respecto a que se colorea el texto al tocarlo y se le va el color al soltarlo. El problema es que el coloreo se le da a todo el texto y no a las partes en específico que yo le asigné. Como puedo corregir esto?

Comment: Ok, si te fijas, el método `setSpan` recibe dos parámetros de posiciones que son los que pintan el texto en el rango seleccionado. En la clase `Clickable` hay 2 métodos: `setPressedTextColor()` y `setDefaultTextColor()` en ambos en `editable.setSpan` debes indicarle la posición del texto que va a pintar, actualmente tiene `0` en inicio y `editable.length()` de final, osea la pintará toda. Debes cambiarla por cual posición en el texto quieres que inicie y termine respectivamente. Si quieres que pinte una palabra en específico, utiliza `String.indexOf`, editaré la respuesta para darte un ejemplo